# Swift 3.0 sort - Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

Tags: swift, swift3

I am currently trying to port some Swift 2 code to Swift 3.0.

Here is one line of code that is driving  me crazy.

```
    public private(set) var searchHistory: [SearchHistoryEntry] = [SearchHistoryEntry]() // Struct that is cComparable 
....
...
    searchHistory.sortInPlace({ $0.lastUsage.isAfter($1.lastUsage) })
```

This is my Swift 3.0 Version

```
searchHistory.sort(by:{ $0.lastUsage.isAfter($1.lastUsage) })
```

lastUsage is of Type **Date**

The Compiler complains with the following error message

**Argument passed to call that takes no arguments**

Any Ideas what I am doing wrong? 
I really don not understand what the compiler wants to tell.
Sort takes a block and I pass it, everything should be fine.

**UPDATE**

I found the mistake. Swift converted all NSDate properties to Date and we got an extension called *isAfter* on NSDate. So the compiler could not found isAfter anymore. The compiler error message was completely misleading.

Comment: What types do `searchHistory` and `lastUsage` have? Can you give more context to your lines of code?

Comment: Sorry, yes i can do that.

Comment: I got that error .. Swift converted all NSDate properties to Date. And we got an extension called isAfter on NSDate. So the compiler could not found isAfter anymore. The compiler error message was completely misleading.

Comment: It's not the first time the swift compiler gives cryptic error messages :)

Comment: Nevertheless, thank you ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would use `sorted(by: )` i.e.

```
searchHistory.sorted(by: {$0.lastUsage > $1.lastUsage})
```

Full working example:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"

struct ExerciseEquipment
{
    let name: String
    let lastUsage: Date
}

let myExerciseEquipment =
[
    ExerciseEquipment(name: "Golf Clubs", lastUsage: dateFormatter.date(from: "03-16-2015")!),
    ExerciseEquipment(name: "Tennis Racket", lastUsage: dateFormatter.date(from: "06-30-2003")!),
    ExerciseEquipment(name: "Skis", lastUsage: dateFormatter.date(from: "02-08-2017")!),
    ExerciseEquipment(name: "Hockey Stick", lastUsage: dateFormatter.date(from: "09-21-2010")!),
    ExerciseEquipment(name: "Mountain Bike", lastUsage: dateFormatter.date(from: "10-30-2016")!)
]

print(myExerciseEquipment.sorted(by: {$0.lastUsage > $1.lastUsage}))
```

...results in

> [ExerciseEquipment(name: "Skis", lastUsage: 2017-02-08 05:00:00
>   +0000), ExerciseEquipment(name: "Mountain Bike", lastUsage: 2016-10-30 04:00:00 +0000), ExerciseEquipment(name: "Golf Clubs", lastUsage:
>   2015-03-16 04:00:00 +0000), ExerciseEquipment(name: "Hockey Stick",
>   lastUsage: 2010-09-21 04:00:00 +0000), ExerciseEquipment(name: "Tennis
>   Racket", lastUsage: 2003-06-30 04:00:00 +0000)]

Answer (score 1):

Just got to the same error. My previous code in Swift was:

```
let sorted =  array.sorted {
    $0.characters.count < $1.characters.count
}
```

However, it is not working anymore. Looks like they've updated `sorted()` with arguments to `sorted(by: )`

The following works for me now:

```
let sorted = array.sorted(by: {x, y -> Bool in 
    x.characters.count < y.characters.count 
})
```