# Sorting mapped array on date SwiftUI

Tags: arrays, sorting, charts, mapping, swiftui

I'm trying to display some Core Data values in a chart using SwiftUI and the AppPear packages (https://github.com/AppPear/ChartView).

My entity looks as following:

```
public class Data: NSManagedObject, Identifiable {
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID
    @NSManaged public var value: Double
    @NSManaged public var valueDescription: String?
    @NSManaged public var date: NSDate
}
```

The goal is to show display 'value' in the chart, with 'date' as the x-axis.

I have been able to display my 'value'-values in the chart as following:

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftUICharts

struct NSFetchArrayTest: View {
        @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: Data.allDataFetchRequest()) var data: FetchedResults<Datas>
        @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            LineView(data: data.map {$0.value}, title: "Test", legend: "None").padding()
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 300, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 300, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }

}
```

However, now the 'value'-values are sorted from low to high. I want them sorted based on the 'date' attribute. Several stack posts suggest to add:

```
sorted(by: { $0.date > $1.date })
```

Which would result in:

```
LineView(data: data.map {$0.value}.sorted(by: { $0.date > $1.date }), title: "Test", legend: "None").padding()
```

This results in the error type:

*Argument passed to call that takes no arguments*.

This post: [Swift 3.0 sort - Argument passed to call that takes no arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38995107/swift-3-0-sort-argument-passed-to-call-that-takes-no-arguments) suggests the same error type, but I have no clue how to amend/change my code in order to make it work.

Does anyone have a clue, or an idea for a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a sortDescriptor to your @FetchRequest to get your results ordered the way you want them to be.

You can do this directly inside your @FetchRequest:

```
@FetchRequest(
    entity: Datas.entity(), 
    sortDescriptors: [
        NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Datas.date, ascending: false)
    ]
) var data: FetchedResults<Datas>
```

or inside your `Data.allDataFetchRequest()`:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Datas>(entityName: "Datas")
let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: \Datas.date, ascending: false)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]
```

You can change the order by changing the `ascending` Property.

Comment: You, sir/lady, are an absolutely legend! I was clearly looking in the wrong place to sort this. It works, many thanks!